# SPContext.Current is null in application page

Tags: 2013, application-pages, spcontext

I created a simple SharePoint solution and added one application page, in code behind I am not able to access `SPContext.Current` because it is returning `null` see below code

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace MyCompany.Sharepoint.Layouts.MyCompany.Sharepoint
{
    public partial class Auth : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SPContext.Current != null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Failled!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am accessing this by this URL

```
http://sharepoint:24357/_layouts/15/MyCompany.Sharepoint/Auth.aspx
```

For more details see discussion under [@Robert Lindgren](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/15141/robert-lindgren)'s answer [SPContext.Current is null in application page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174409/spcontext-current-is-null-in-application-page/174411#174411)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different base class for the page if you want `SPContext` on it:

Use `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.LayoutsPageBase` instead, detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.aspx)

Comment: I just changed this line 'public partial class Auth : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.LayoutsPageBase' and when I access page with same URL showing '404 FILE NOT FOUND'

Comment: Please doublecheck that the file actually is still present in the correct location in 15 hive

Comment: Yes it exists I checked in this location 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MyCompany.Sharepoint'

Comment: OK, so something is fishy with how it was originally created. Please recreate it following these steps: 1. In Solution Explorer, choose your project.
2. On the menu bar, choose Project, Add New Item.
3. In the Add New Item dialog box, choose the Application Page (Farm Solution Only) template.

Comment: I created new page and facing same issue http://sharepoint:24357/_layouts/15/MyCompany.Sharepoint/Authentication.aspx   404 FILE NOT FOUND

Comment: This page also exists in directory C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MyCompany.Sharepoint

Comment: Are you using a custom masterpage or something? Just creating a plain one (without modifying it) and deploy the solution should work if there isn't a more serious issue in your environment

Comment: I am customizing page Auth.aspx but newly created Authentication.aspx is just default page, Can you guide how can I diagnose it?

Comment: You should look in ULS-logs when loading the page to see exactly what is happening ad throwing the 404